# What's the measure of the angle $ \measuredangle OBH$?

Tags: plane-geometry

For reference: In an acute triangle ABC, H is the orthocenter and O is the circumcenter. Find the $ \measuredangle OBH, if ~\measuredangle A - \measuredangle C=24^o $

My progresss:
I made the drawing and the following relationships

$\measuredangle AOC = 2(\alpha +\theta)\\
\triangle AOB ~and ~\triangle BOC~and \triangle AOC~are ~isosceles\\
\measuredangle DAO = 90^o -(\alpha+\theta)\implies \measuredangle ABE = \theta\\
\measuredangle DAB=90-\theta $
[image]

Comment: You mean $\measuredangle DAB$ or $\measuredangle BAE = 90^\circ - \theta$ at last?

Comment: distraction of mine, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram already shows it: $\angle OBH$ is the red angle;

$$\angle OBH = \alpha - \theta$$

And from the given,

$$\alpha - \theta = \angle A - \angle C = 24^\circ$$